# how to associate multiple files in c#

Tags: c#, associations

When i select multiple files in my computer and open , each file open with one instance in my application. in configure windows application to run one instance,but one file open with my application.How can i open selected files and add address files in a list box in my application.

program.cs

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args != null && args.Length > 0)
        {
            string fileName = args[0];
            if (File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

                Form1 MainFrom = new Form1();
                MainFrom.OpenFile(fileName);
                Application.Run(MainFrom);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The file does not exist!", "BMPlayer Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Application.Run(new Form1());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

Form.cs

```
        public void OpenFile(string filePath)
    {
        string file1 = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = filePath;
    }
```

this code only work for one file.

Comment: Have you tried anything ? Do you have any code to share with example data ? It is not clear to me what do you want to achieve.

Comment: Also, You Should Not Put A Capital Letter To Each Word of your sentences.

Comment: I understand you are not a native english speaker. Let me take an attempt on straitening that question and please tell if it hits the nail: In Explorer, you want to select multiple files. Now if you hit enter you want your Application to open with a list of those selected files instead of one instance of your application for each selected file. Your attempt to configure your Application so only one instance can be open at a time lead to the behavior that there is only one instance with one file from the selection. Is that correct?

Comment: for single file it works fine, but when I try to open multiple files at the same time it starts an instance of the program for each individual file.

Comment: it's not my question @Fildor , and i copied from other websites. 
And the mistakes are because of that Pac0:)

Comment: I copied because it's my problem too. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the type of your desktop project, but you can do it in WinForms using the method below:

```
private void OpenFiles()
    {            
        using (var openFolderDialog = new OpenFileDialog { Multiselect = true })
        {
            openFolderDialog.Filter = "csv files (*.csv)|*.csv|txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";

            if (openFolderDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK
                && openFolderDialog.FileNames.All(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)))
            {
                string[] files = openFolderDialog.FileNames;

                // TO DO: You can now loop over the selected files
                foreach(var fileName in files)
                {
                    // Addyour logic here
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Example of program using Windows Media Player to player a list of song files from one WMP single process like a play list:

```
class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string space = " ";
        string filePath1 = @"D:\mysong1.mp3";
        string filePath2 = @"D:\mysong2.mp3";            

        List<string> songFiles = new List<string>();
        songFiles.Add(filePath1);
        songFiles.Add(filePath2);            

        var playList = songFiles.Aggregate((a, b) => a + space + b);

        Process.Start("wmplayer.exe", playList);            
    }
}
```

You can use the combination of the two codes above to accomplish your need.

Comment: I don't mean open file dialog project .my program is a music player and when you double-click on a music , it's going to play that well,but when you select more than one song ,the program open the songs in more instance

Comment: I wan't to select and play more than one song in one instance ,just like playlist.Besides that i know how to create a playlist in c# :)
So my question is not "how to create a playlist"

Comment: I see what you mean, but if you want more help you should add some of your code to point out precisely where the issue is. Otherwise, i could simply tell you to use the code above, and loop over the selected music files and implement foreach file the logic to play it and close it when it's finished.

Comment: what is the object axWindowsMediaPlayer1 ?

Comment: it's from com component . WMP object.

Comment: Here's an example i've just tested and it works fine with one single process of Windows Media Player: (please see my edit)

Comment: i know your answer will work. But I do not want to give a specific path to the program to play a multiple songs. My program is such that the user clicks on the song and plays the song.

Comment: It was just an example, you can easily implement an event handler to do your requirement.

Comment: I can't fix my problem.can you do what your said with my code please?